# How to repair exposed exterior foundation insulation?

Tags: insulation, foundation

Thanks for checking this question.  New to owning a home, and new to stack exchange.  I do not know where to begin and I do not know what "terms" to use when googling.  Any tips/ideas how to repair or replace exposed foundation foam insulation?  Thank you!

[image: Is the yellow part the exposed insulation, gray material is the plastic cover?]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Some more details would help: is the foam in a sheet, or does it look like expanded and hardened (and orange) whipped cream? How big is the exposed area? Would a simple cover like that gray sheet metal nearby work?

Comment: Thanks for your response!  The foam seems like some kind of wall panel similar to sheet rock but it is some hardened foam.  The gray cover is actually plastic material but I can't seem to find this in Home Depot or other home improvement stores.  I'm afraid I'm going to have to dig out the area, rip it out and replace it with a new insulation panel (if I find any) and eventually cover with something from fauxpanels.com.  However, I have no idea what I'm talking about and if that is even best practice.

Comment: Good information, but it's best if you edit this into your question.